# Memory interfacing and IO interfacing

Tags: memory, io

What is the difference between memory interfacing and IO interfacing ?

Comment: by the way i search about this at google but i couldn't find a right answer :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a book entitled "Microprocessors" on Google books. In chapter 8, the book defines "Memory and I/O Interfacing". You can read the related pages from [here](http://books.google.com.tr/books?id=qoJBa2jR3p0C&pg=SA8-PA1&lpg=SA8-PA1&dq=%22memory+interfacing%22+vs.+%22I/O+interfacing%22&source=bl&ots=shctCmwfvU&sig=jWOI1uvie4r6ejaTAL-cj7WmDwk&hl=tr&ei=qDP8S9eRKdiS4gaDmd3mAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Also, [this](http://www.brighthub.com/engineering/electrical/articles/53885.aspx) article defines Memory Interfacing and I/O Interfacing. The following is an excerpt from the article:

> **Memory Interfacing:**
>
> While executing an instruction, there is a necessity for the
>   microprocessor to access memory frequently for reading various
>   instruction codes and data stored in the memory. The interfacing
>   circuit aids in accessing the memory.
>
> Memory requires some signals to read from and write to registers.
>   Similarly the microprocessor transmits some signals for reading or
>   writing a data.
>
> But what is the purpose of interfacing circuit here?
>
> The interfacing process involves matching the memory requirements with
>   the microprocessor signals. The interfacing circuit therefore should
>   be designed in such a way that it matches the memory signal
>   requirements with the signals of the microprocessor. For example for
>   carrying out a READ process, the microprocessor should initiate a read
>   signal which the memory requires to read a data. In simple words, the
>   primary function of a memory interfacing circuit is to aid the
>   microprocessor in reading and writing a data to the given register of
>   a memory chip.
>
> **I/O Interfacing:**
>
> We know that keyboard and Displays are used as communication channel
>   with outside world. So it is necessary that we interface keyboard and
>   displays with the microprocessor. This is called I/O interfacing. In
>   this type of interfacing we use latches and buffers for interfacing
>   the keyboards and displays with the microprocessor.
>
> But the main disadvantage with this interfacing is that the
>   microprocessor can perform only one function. It functions as an input
>   device if it is connected to buffer and as an output device if it is
>   connected to latch. Thus the capability is very limited in this type
>   of interfacing.